# What does Mohamed El-Erian mean by "recovery value of assets"?

Tags: economic-terms

Pls see the emboldened phrase. [Investors must prepare portfolios for Covid-19 debt crunch | Financial Times](https://www.ft.com/content/fcfa2827-35c7-47fb-b5c1-c97f8c841a56)

> The financial stress caused by Covid-19 is far from over. Investors should brace for non-payments to spread far beyond the most vulnerable corporate and sovereign borrowers, in a reckoning that threatens to drag prices lower.
>
> There is still time to get ahead of this trend. Rather than buying assets at valuations stunningly decoupled from underlying corporate and economic fundamentals, investors should think a lot more about the **recovery value of their assets** and adjust their portfolios accordingly.
>
> So far, despite signs of rising stress on corporate and public balance sheets, non-payments have been largely contained to certain badly affected segments.
>
> But the sense that the worst did not come to pass has fed complacency among investors of all stripes. A new generation of retail investors has emerged, helping stocks on their relentless [march higher](https://www.ft.com/content/1dfaeb58-6d65-4f17-b710-b1ebc6622649).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recovery value normally refers to the liquidation value of assets after a corporate bankruptcy. In most cases, this is well below the value of a functioning corporation (its value as a going concern). There can be exceptions; a poorly run retailer with valuable real estate.

El-Erian is just using jargon incorrectly to impress people.